# How to find the program responsible for a specific TCP socket (linux)

Tags: linux, tcp, port, lsof, activemq

```
joe@server:~$ sudo lsof -i :36168
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    23059 activemq   15u  IPv6 109382      0t0  TCP *:36168 (LISTEN)
```

From the output above I want to disable port 36168, but don't know where. How can I exactly find the configuration file of this port to modify it?

*grep* ing for this doesn't give a result. And I don't want to use a firewall instead.

Comment: In this case it was probably a dynamic port of activemq. Closing all connections to aptivemq and restart the service let the port disappear.

Comment: Would you mind selecting one of the answers?

Answer (score 1):

From your `lsof` output, you have the `PID` number of the process which has the port open.  Do `ps -AH` to see a hierarchical listing of processes and look for that specific `PID`.  This process will be indented 'below' other processes, scan up the tree until you find the parent process (if you reach `init` you've gone too far, go back down one level).

Once you've identified the parent process, you should then be able to stop that process using your distribution's `init` scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I always found fuser easier

```
fuser 80/tcp
```

It will list all the pids running on port 80 using tcp

Answer (score 1):

```
netstat -putan | grep 80 | grep LISTEN
```

gives

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1682/apache2
```

As you can see, apache2 with PID=1682 is the process listening on port 80 in this example.

Answer (score 0):

The well-known ports are in /etc/services.
The port mentioned seems to be used by activemq, maybe it's not standardized. Please see the configuration of activemq, or the deployed webapps if it's running in web container. You can secure the installation if you make it bind on the local address (127.0.0.1 or ::1). If you don't need activemq, simply stop the application.